# How can I create multiple chart areas on ms chart or ... c#

Tags: c#, mschart

Hello I need to make a chart like this :
[http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=USD}&to=EUR](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=USD%7D&to=EUR)

Should I use 2 chart areas or just create 2 charts

Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created 2 charts with same series a small one and a big one selecting on big one zoomes on the small one